# What is this low-growing weed with purple flowers in Australia?

Tags: weed-control, weeds

Can anyone please tell me what type of weed this is? It is growing spread throughout an area of grass/lawn, in mid-spring in Toowoomba, Australia.

What would be an effective method to control it?

[image: suspicious looking plant/weed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slender vervain, *Verbena rigidia* http://bie.ala.org.au/species/VERBENA+RIGIDA#

https://www.moretonbay.qld.gov.au/uploadedFiles/moretonbay/environment/vegetation/purple-top.pdf has some control methods.  I've never had this as a weed.  I ID'd it on it's similarity to verbenas I know and went from there...